# SassError: @use rules must be written before any other rules. Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

The error content:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You must put any `@use` line of code above others.

For example the code below throws error:

```
.button {
  @include corners.rounded;
  padding: 5px + corners.$radius;
}

@use "src/corners";
```

But this code will work fine:

```
@use "src/corners";

.button {
  @include corners.rounded;
  padding: 5px + corners.$radius;
}
```

Remember that `@use` in the middle lines will throw error even if you don't use anything from the file.